# put links without file extension (.php)

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to configure Apache in order not to show a file extension?

For example: Say I have `domain.com/page.php` but want to have `domain.com/page` as the url.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called URL rewriting. I had to use it for the first time recently and i used [this tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) to learn it, hope you'll find it great too :

Answer (score 54):

Put this is your .htaccess file

```
#turn on url rewriting 
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This allows you to access .php files without the extension, so your links should read

```
href="/somepage"
```

and this will direct to

```
href="/somepage.php"
```

Answer (score 15):

There is also `MultiViews` as a vhost or .htaccess configuration option.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

From that page:

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

Comment: Multiviews can be quite annoying, and get in the way of normal mod_rewrite rules if the choice of filenames and rewrite patterns overlaps.

Comment: Very true.  Use with caution.

Comment: I added MultiViews in my vhost suffered for 2 days. I was unable to figure out why my clean get request url was not working.... Thanks @TheGingerDog

Comment: The comment from @DavidGoodwin and this answer really helped solve a particularly nasty and hard to track conflict between rewrite rules and the MultiViews option enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Put this is your .htaccess file

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page?$ page.php
```

```html
<a href="page">page</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want a web server feature called URL rewriting - every web server application (apache, IIS, nginx) supports this. As the name suggests, it takes the requested URL and rewrites it into a specific format that you define.

There are many guides available on the www, even if you are using shared hosting solution you can still add/modify the .htaccess file to do this.