# .htaccess rewrite rule is only working when .php is in the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the domain `example.com` with several external domains pointed to it in different directories.

I have the following `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap urlmap txt:/var/www/html/map.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${urlmap:%{HTTP_HOST}}/$1
```

The problem with this is that I cannot open files without adding the `.php` extension to the end of the URL.

For example, `cool.com` points to `example.com/someuser` and that works fine - probably because it automatically points to **index.php**.

If I choose to visit `cool.com/file`, I am greeted with a 404 error:

**The requested URL /someuser/file.php was not found on this server.**

However, if I choose to visit `cool.com/file.php`, everything works perfectly for some reason.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Take a look on response bellow, it may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018569/6713425